# how to generate thumbnails in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, image-processing, paperclip

I'am trying to generate thumbnails with uploaded images in CakePHP.

I have worked with Rails and I used paperclip for that purpose, is there any way to do the same with CakePHP?

to be clear, I want to shrink the images keeping the ratio and then crop them in order to get them in the size I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have PHP available, you can try [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/), which does all that for you and much more. It can crop, zoom-crop, transform, blur, contrast...etc etc, and it auto-creates the thumbnails and keeps them in cache so it doesn't have to re-crop...etc each time the image is loaded.

It's also VERY simple to install and use, which is a big plus.

For CakePHP, you can just put the phpthumb folder in your webroot/ directory and use it just like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be looking for something like my [Polyclip plugin](https://github.com/robwilkerson/CakePHP-Polyclip-Plugin). It's not feature-complete so I haven't documented it very well yet (I'll work on that as soon as I can), but it is in production and the core functionality that's in place seems to do what I need. Here's how I have it deployed with an `Attraction` model.

```
public $actsAs = array(
  'Polyclip.attachable' => array(
    'Image' => array(
      'Thumbnails' => array(
        'medium'  => array( 'width' => 250, 'height' => 250, 'method' => 'resize_to_fit' ),
        'square'  => array( 'width' => 100, 'height' => 100, 'method' => 'resize_to_fill' ),
        'sidebar' => array( 'width' => 290, 'height' => 100, 'method' => 'resize_to_fill' )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

This attaches an image to the attraction with 3 thumbnails created automatically. As I said, it's not documented, but it's out there to fill the need you're looking to fill.

Comment: Where does it get/save the images from? Is there a way to specify it directly in the model? Thanks.

Comment: Look in app/config/install. There's a SQL file to create the necessary tables.